# Is there any difference between UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes and Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

Today I saw a code in which `UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` is used. Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No difference at all.

[`Encoding.UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) *is* `UTF8Encoding`.

From MSDN (`Encoding.UTF8`):

> This property returns a UTF8Encoding object

Instead of `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` you can simply call `UTF8Encoding.GetBytes`.

Comment: Granted, the documentation at the time (.NET Framework 4) did not mention it, but the current documentation (.NET Framework 4.5) says that it is equivalent to `new UTF8Encoding(true)`, which will emit a BOM.

Comment: Also, @JonHanna's answer seems to better address the actual question: whether `UTF8Encoding.UTF8` is different from `Encoding.UTF8`.

Answer (score 12):

There is at least one difference. Encoding.UTF8 will write BOM while UTF8Encoding will not (by default). Check this out:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

class UTF8EncodingExample {
    public static void Main() {
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        UTF8Encoding utf8EmitBOM = new UTF8Encoding(true);

        Console.WriteLine("utf8 preamble:");
        ShowArray(utf8.GetPreamble());

        Console.WriteLine("utf8EmitBOM:");
        ShowArray(utf8EmitBOM.GetPreamble());

        Console.WriteLine("Encoding.UTF8 preamble:");
        ShowArray(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
   }

    public static void ShowArray(Array theArray) {
        foreach (Object o in theArray) {
            Console.Write("[{0}]", o);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew they were different in that respect, just couldn't rememember which would write the BOM. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

UTF8Encoding inherits its static UTF8 property from Encoding, so they are in fact the same property.

Comment: I guess something went wrong in the design of those classes. The ability to call `UTF8Encoding.ASCII` seems odd.

Comment: @Stijn not terribly. For one thing, why would you? (why would you even bother calling `UTF8Encoding.UTF8` for that matter?), for another, "know stuff about encodings" falls under the conceptual role of a specific encoding, so to be able to from "here" to "there" isn't dreadful.

Comment: Of course you wouldn't do that, but it does create confusion for consumers of the classes. Encoding is already a complex topic, so imho, having to thoroughly read documentation and other resources on the internet to make sure my understanding is correct is an indication of non-optimal design.

Comment: @Stijn well firstly, you should be used to the idea that static members get inherited, and secondly the design is such that you should generally only need to study the documentation for `Encoding` as the only members `UTF8Encoding` has that neither inherit nor override are the constructors.
One could make a case for not exposing the type `UTF8Encoding` at all, and have all the variants the constructor offers available through static methods of `Encoding` returning `Encoding` and the implemntation being hidden.

Comment: It's just simple inheritance. A subclass retains the public statics of the superclass. I don't think there's anything you _can_ do about that.

Answer (score 3):

These are just two different ways to access the `UTF8Encoding` class and call its static member `GetBytes`.